# how to use multiprocessing map_async with a callback function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use map_async of multiprocessing.Pool. In this minimal example. A classe attribute i should be increased and a counter in the callback function should be increased. However, the callback function appears to be never called.

```
import random
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


class BuyerAgent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

class ZITraders:
    def __init__(self):
        self.max_number_of_trades = 5000

        self.buyers = [BuyerAgent()
                       for _ in xrange(5000)]


    def do_trading(self):
        counter = 0
        dd = 0

        def cb(datuum):
            dd = datuum
            counter += 1
            print 'cb'

        po = Pool()
        po.map_async(match, reverb(self.buyers, self.buyers, self.max_number_of_trades), callback=cb)
        po.close()
        po.join()
        print counter, dd


def reverb(buyers, sellers, num):
    for n in xrange(num):
        yield random.choice(buyers), random.choice(sellers)


def match(buyer, seller):
    print 'match'
    buyer.i += 1
    return buyer.i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time()
    simulation = ZITraders()
    simulation.do_trading()
    print('time %2.2f' % (time() - t))
```

Result:

```
MacBook-Pro:zi taghawi$ python zitraders.py
0 0
time 0.13
```